# Semântica para sub-páginas no HTML5

Tags: html5, semântica

Seria correto utilizar o código conforme abaixo?

```
<article>
  ...
  <section>
    <article>...</article>
    <article>...</article>
    <article>...</article>
  </section>
</article>
```

Caso não, qual seria a melhor forma relacionar as sub-páginas ao article principal?

Comment: Se são sub-páginas, por quê estariam no mesmo arquivo?

Comment: Pois seria um resumo das sub-páginas, com links "Leia mais" para ir para a sub-página completa

Comment: Então acredito que seja `<aside>`, visto que não fazem parte do conteúdo principal da página.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui tem um excelente artigo do HTML5 Doctor e o exemplo que ele usa é muito próximo do seu veja:

*"Um `<article>` com `<section>`s

Você pode usar o elemento `<section>` para dividir o `<article>` em grupos lógicos de conteúdo com títulos"*

> **An `<article>` with `<section>`s** 
>   You can use the `<section>` element to split the article into logical groups of content with headings:

```
<article>
  <h1>Apple varieties</h1>
  <p>The apple is the pomaceous fruit of the apple tree...</p>

  <section>
    <h2>Red Delicious</h2>
    <p>These bright red apples are the most common found in many supermarkets...</p>
  </section>

  <section>
    <h2>Granny Smith</h2>
    <p>These juicy, green apples make a great filling for apple pies...</p>
  </section>

</article>
```

**FONTE:** Aqui tem o artigo completo, outros exemplos, e inclusive uma explicação sobre a diferença entre `<article>` e `<section>` na qual ele explica que o `article` tem mais valor semântico que o section

- http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/

---

**TL;DR**

Exite muita confusão sobre a diferença entre os elementos `<article>` e `<section>`. O elemento `<article>` é um tipo especializado de `<section>`; tem um significado semântico mais específico do que `<section>` até pelo fato de ser um bloco independente e autônomo de conteúdo. Poderíamos usar `<section>`, mas usando `<article>` dá mais significado semântico ao conteúdo.

Por outro lado, `<section>` é apenas um bloco de conteúdo relacionado e `<div>` é apenas um bloco de conteúdo.

Para decidir qual desses três elementos é apropriado, escolha a primeira opção adequada:

- O conteúdo faria sentido sozinho em um leitor de feeds? Se sim, use `<article>` ***(conteúdo independente)***
- O conteúdo está relacionado? Se sim, use `<section>` ***(section dentro do article)***
- Finalmente, se não houver relacionamento semântico, use `<div>` ***(div dentro do article)***

*(o trecho acima foi retirado do artigo citado)*

***Agora as palavras do Dr. Bruce Lawson:***

**Sobre o article**

> The spec says “When article elements are nested, the inner article elements represent articles that are in principle related to the contents of the outer article.”

*Tradução simplificada:* Quando os elementos `article`s são aninhados os `article`s dentro dos `article`s representam artigos que, em princípio, estão relacionados ao conteúdo do `article` externo".

**Sobre o section**

> Section, on the other hand, isn’t “a self-contained composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is intended to be independently distributable or reusable”. It’s either a way of sectioning a page into different subject areas, or sectioning an article into … well, sections.

*Tradução simplificada:* A `section`, por outro lado, não é “uma composição autônoma em um documento, página, aplicativo ou site e que se destina a ser distribuída ou reutilizável de forma independente”. `Section` é uma maneira de dividir uma página em diferentes áreas de assunto ou de dividir um `article` em bem... seções.

*Fonte:* http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2010/html5-articles-and-sections-whats-the-difference/

Comment: Utilizar um `<article>` com múltiplos `<section>` é diferente de usar um `<section>` com múltiplos `<article>`. Se entendi bem, a dúvida é como representar sub-páginas dentro da página e não sub-seções da própria, o que, semanticamente, faz toda a diferença. Acho que se você trazer a diferença entre os elementos para a resposta será mais esclarecedor.

Comment: Legal @AndersonCarlosWoss incluí algumas infos adicionais. Eu entendi que o autor da pergunta queria secionar páginas de conteúdo independente dentro de um página pai. No caso entendi que seri algo como `article pai` > `section com filhos` > `article para cada filho independente`